# Javascript plugin creation methods

Tags: javascript

I want to create a plugin 'myPlugin' which simply add some text to a div. like:

```
 document.getElementById('testDiv').myPlugin("this is a text");
```

how can I achieve this through singleton method as well as prototype method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function appendTextToElement(element, text) {
  var textProperty = element.innerText === undefined ? "textContent" : "innerText";
  element[textProperty] = element[textProperty] + text;
}
```

And a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/RrsVa/).

Answer (score 0):

```
HTMLElement.prototype.myPlugin = function(t) {
    // ...
}
```

Will add a method to all HTML elements in compliant browsers. It won't work on IE though (at least on the old versions, I honestly haven't tried in IE8).

What do you mean by "singleton method"?

Comment: Hi matti, thanks for your replay.
I don't want to extend the HTMLElement object. I want something like:

function myPlugin() {
this.create = function(text){
 div.innerHTML = text;
};
}

or 

var myPlugin = {
     create:function(text){
     div.innerHTML = text;
     }
}

I'm basically a designer, not much programming knowlwdge.

Comment: And... the code you just posted doesn't do what you'd like it to do?